# How does Rust understand to call the appropriate implementation of from_iter using only FromIterator::from_iter?

Tags: rust, traits

An iterator can be transformed to a collection using the `Iterator` trait's `collect` method if the collection implements `FromIterator`.

```
let vec = (0..10).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let devec = (0..10).collect::<VecDeque<_>>();
```

`Vec` and `VecDeque` implement `FromIterator` trait.

The implementation of `Iterator::collect` method is:

```
fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    FromIterator::from_iter(self)
}
```

How does Rust understand to call `from_iter` method of `Vec` or `VecDeque` from `FromIterator::from_iter(self)`?

Comment: You can write `let vec: Vec<_> = (0..10).collect()` instead, which infers the type the same way (and is slightly more idiomatic IMO)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the `FromIterator` trait has an implementor, it has the form:

```
impl<T> FromIterator<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Vec<T> { /* ... */ }
}
```

It returns the concrete type `Self`; that is the generic parameter `B` in the `collect` code.

When you type `collect::<Vec<_>>()`, you say that `B` is `Vec<_>` and therefore, that `Vec<_>::from_iter()` must be called.

The implementation of `collect` could have been written: `<B as FromIterator>::from_iter(self)`, but it is more verbose.

Comment: Thanks. <B as FromIterator>::from_iter(self) hits the point i am looking for.

Comment: @nyinyithann If the implementation was written as `<B as FromIterator>::from_iter(self)`, Rust would not need to infer the type, since it's expicitly given. If you don't explicitly specify the type, Rust needs to infer the type based on the information it has, and my understanding of your question has been that you are asking how Rust is performing the type inference. Is this not what you meant?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Not particularly about type inference. Just wondering about FromIterator::from_iter(self).

Comment: @nyinyithann OK, never mind then, I have misread your question. My answer may still be useful for other people dropping by, so I'll leave it up.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for your answer too. Got a pointer to learn more about Rust's type inference.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the definition of the `FromIterator` trait:

```
pub trait FromIterator<A>: Sized {
    fn from_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = A>>(iter: T) -> Self;
}
```

From how `FromIterator::from_iter()` is used in the implementation of the `collect()` method, Rust knows that the call to `FromIterator::from_iter()` takes the iterator `self` as parameter, and returns an object of type `B`. This information is matched against the definition of the `from_iter()` method, so Rust can conclude that the `Self` type of the `FromIterator` trait implementation must be `B`, and that the type `A` must be the item type of the iterator. The `Self` type of the `FromIterator` trait is precisely the type Rust needs to call `from_iter()` for.

The details of how type inference works are complex. Rust uses a variant of the Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm. You can find some further information in [this document from the rustc guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-guide/blob/master/src/type-inference.md).

Roughly, Rust uses all information it has about unknown types as constraints and iteratively refines its knowledge about generic types, until only a single type for each unknown type remains, or some type remains ambiguous. In the former case, type inference was successful and all types have been inferred, and in the latter case, Rust will throw an error stating that it needs further type annotations.